# How two merge two dataframes without any index being based

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have two dataframes X and Y:

```
import pandas as pd
X = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,7],'B':[2,5,8],'C':[3,6,9]})
Y = pd.DataFrame({'D':[1],'E':[11]})


In [4]: X
Out[4]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
In [6]: Y
Out[6]:
   D   E
0  1  11
```

and then, I want to get the following result dataframe:

```
  A B C D E
0 1 2 3 1 11
1 4 5 6 1 11
2 7 8 9 1 11
```

how？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `Y` contains only one row:

```
In [9]: X.assign(**Y.to_dict('r')[0])
Out[9]:
   A  B  C  D   E
0  1  2  3  1  11
1  4  5  6  1  11
2  7  8  9  1  11
```

or a much nicer alternative from [@piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43849998/how-two-merge-two-dataframes-without-any-index-being-based/43850068?noredirect=1#comment74738006_43850068):

```
In [27]: X.assign(**Y.iloc[0])
Out[27]:
   A  B  C  D   E
0  1  2  3  1  11
1  4  5  6  1  11
2  7  8  9  1  11
```

Helper dict:

```
In [10]: Y.to_dict('r')[0]
Out[10]: {'D': 1, 'E': 11}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Comment: It does help! But would you mind explaining it more clearly? I don't get it how this happens. Thank you. What is the '**'  ?

Comment: [keyword argument unpacking](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131403/what-is-the-name-of-in-python)

Comment: @ Scott Boston Thank you.

Comment: @ScottBoston, thank you, i had a short stand-up meeting, so i couldn't answer :)

Comment: Shorter `X.assign(**Y.loc[0])`

Comment: @piRSquared, that's beautiful, thank you! But frankly speaking i don't understand how does it work... ;-)

Comment: @MaxU it's the same as your concept.  Meaning I'm using `**` to unpack a dictionary`.  However, I use `Y.loc[0]` to get the first row of `Y` and I trust that `pandas` will unpack a series appropriately when used in a dictionary context.... and it does.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way

`Y2 = pd.concat([Y]*3, ignore_index = True)` #This duplicates the rows

Which produces:

```
    D   E
0   1   11
0   1   11
0   1   11
```

Then concat once again:

```
pd.concat([X,Y2], axis =1)



    A   B   C   D   E
0   1   2   3   1   11
1   4   5   6   1   11
2   7   8   9   1   11
```